# Gridview update issue - .NET

Tags: c#, mysql, .net

I have the gridview pulling the data I want however I added a button that when the button is clicked it updates the lastLeak to a date I set... I know the query works in SQL so not sure what I am missing to make it work...

```
 <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataSourceID="lastLeakCheck" Width="850px">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="customerName" HeaderText="customer Name" SortExpression="customerName" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="acctNum" HeaderText="acct Num" SortExpression="acctNum" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="phoneNum" HeaderText="phone Num" SortExpression="phoneNum" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="city" HeaderText="city" SortExpression="city" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="address" HeaderText="address" SortExpression="address" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="lastLeak" HeaderText="Last Leak" SortExpression="lastLeak" />
        <asp:ButtonField ButtonType="Button" CommandName="Update" HeaderText="Update Date" ShowHeader="True" Text="Completed"  />
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="lastLeakCheck" runat="server" ConnectionString="Data Source=server;Initial Catalog=propane;User ID=user;Password=pass;Integrated Security=True" SelectCommand="SELECT customerName, acctNum, phoneNum, city, address, lastLeak from custInfo WHERE lastLeak &lt;= CONVERT(datetime, '4-6-2012' ) ORDER BY CONVERT(DATETIME, lastLeak) ASC"  UpdateCommand = "UPDATE custInfo SET lastLeak='4/5/2017'WHERE customerName='@customerName';"></asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Here is my button click:

```
    cn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=server;Initial Catalog=propane;User ID=id;Password=pass;Integrated Security=True");


    cmd = new SqlCommand("UPDATE custInfo SET lastLeak='4/5/2017' WHERE customerName='@customerName'", cn);

    cn.Open();

    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: Post your button click code

Comment: so what is the error?? post your error

Comment: Ramisha it gives no error.. it clicks and nothing happens... now if I change it to customer name = @customerName it gives me Must declare the scalar variable error... I don't know why it wouldn't update the way its programmed..

Comment: How do I reference that button field I guess is my question....

Comment: Add a space between "'4/5/2017'" and "WHERE"

Comment: @Kris i posted it above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the complete solution I have create a web page and data table and tested this. [Uploaded](http://sthotraani.com/sotest.zip) to one of my website you can download if needed

```
  <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False"  Width="850px" onrowcommand="GridView1_RowCommand">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="customerName" HeaderText="customerName" SortExpression="customerName" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="acctNum" HeaderText="acctNum" SortExpression="acctNum" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="phoneNum" HeaderText="phoneNum" SortExpression="phoneNum" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="city" HeaderText="city" SortExpression="city" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="address" HeaderText="address" SortExpression="address" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="lastLeak" HeaderText="lastLeak" SortExpression="lastLeak" />
        <asp:ButtonField ButtonType="Button" CommandName="UpdateLeak" HeaderText="Update Date" ShowHeader="True" Text="Completed"   />
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Page load

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                BindLeaks();
            }
        }
```

Bind leaks to grid

```
private void BindLeaks()
        {
            using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["LeakConnection"].ConnectionString))
            {
                SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT CustomerName, AcctNum, PhoneNum, City, Address, LastLeak from Leak WHERE lastLeak >= CONVERT(datetime, '4-6-2012') ORDER BY LastLeak ASC", conn);
                DataSet dsLeaks = new DataSet();
                conn.Open();
                da.Fill(dsLeaks);
                conn.Close();
                GridView1.DataSource = dsLeaks;
                GridView1.DataBind();
            }

        }
```

Row command event to update data

```
protected void GridView1_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.CommandName == "UpdateLeak")
            {
                if (e.CommandArgument != null)
                {
                    int RowID = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);
                    GridViewRow row = GridView1.Rows[RowID];
                    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["LeakConnection"].ConnectionString))
                    {
                        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("UPDATE Leak SET lastLeak='4/5/2017' WHERE CustomerName=@customerName", conn);
                        if (e.CommandArgument != null)
                            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@customerName", row.Cells[0].Text.Trim());
                        conn.Open();
                        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        conn.Close();
                        BindLeaks();

                    }

                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: I have tried and tried to get it when that button is clicked to pop up and ask "Are You Sure?" Then if YES is hit go through with the SQL command if no then bring back.... I can't seem to find a click event like you would normally do I even tried adding a Message box before the SqlCommand and nothing.. any ideas?

Comment: Use a template column and put JavaScript on client click or use jQuery and register click event for existing button field

Comment: got that working just need to figure out how now to take the values from the textboxes in the popup and send those to a SQL table!

Comment: Here is a thread I am running @Krishna... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43549335/javascript-popup-in-gridview-that-user-then-can-send-information-to-sql-database

Comment: Good to know you figured it out.